# How to use animated weather icons

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, weather

I am searching for some animated weather icons for android project. I found one of the following skycons. Can anybody tell me if this can be used in a android label or view. Any small  example is appropriated.sorry I could not find one.

http://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/

If any other similar link available?

Comment: The sample script in the link has a comment regarding Android, so it looks like it could work... The catch is that the icons are procedurally generated using Javascript & HTML5, which means that *if* it works, it's most likely in a `WebView` only. If you're feeling adventurous, you can take the [source code](https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons/blob/master/skycons.js) and have a crack at writing one or more [custom views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) that perform the same drawing routines.

Comment: Scratch that last suggestion: [it's already been done](https://github.com/torryharris/Skycons)!

Comment: Dear DownVoters, Could you please specify the reason why you downvoted? So that I can correct. Thanks Biswajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MH told it is implemented https://github.com/torryharris/Skycons.